# Not using Math.Truncate properly. Trying to show 26 instead of 26.8 in C#

Tags: c#, double, rounding

I'm creating a console application that checks if guy has beaten the record for climbing a mountain. There is a catch that says the guy loses 30 seconds every 50 meters i named this varible "wastedTime" and if its 26.5 seconds i want it to be calculated as 26 instead of 27 this is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double record = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        double range = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        double timeForOneMeter = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        double time = timeForOneMeter * range;

        double wastedTime = Math.Truncate((range / 50) * 30);
        double georgesTime = time + (wastedTime);

        Console.WriteLine(wastedTime);

        if (georgesTime<=record)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Yes! The new record is {georgesTime:f2} seconds.");
        }
        else if (georgesTime>record)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"No! He was {georgesTime-record:f2} seconds slower.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pay attention to what values you input into your program. Maybe you make wrong calculations in your head or in your code, so your expectation doesn't match the code's behavior. Debug your code to understand how it works. If you understand how it works, you understand what it does wrong. If you are unfamiliar with debugging, here is a nice guide that should hopefully easy you into it (assuming you are Visual Studio): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp

Comment: In addition, perhaps you should provide a code sample with input values that are giving wrong result hard-coded, instead of doing `Console.ReadLine()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.Floor` method, documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.floor?view=net-6.0).

> Returns the largest integral value less than or equal to the specified number.

For example:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(Math.Floor(26.99d));
// outputs: 26
```

C# Fiddle with example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qM2IDG).

Comment: still same output

Comment: @KristiyanArnaudov Still same output, because you have a problem elsewhere in the code. How about this: `double wastedTime = Math.Floor((range / 50d) * 30);`